# Java XML -LSResourceResolver throw an error

Tags: java, xml, xerces

I have 4 files, 2 xsd and 2 xml (all of them are [here](https://pastebin.com/Xs0MsEdb)), located in `mocks` folder (these are 4 separate files, here they are all together just for show, but the content is accurate).
I also have a custom `LSResourceResolver` ([here](https://pastebin.com/27NXtHs5)).

Now: when I run the following test

```java
 @Test
    public void TestStreamingFromFile2() throws SAXException, IOException {
        String XmlSchemaFile = "../mocks/xsd/Person.xsd";
        String xmlFile = "../mocks/person.xml";
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = null;
        schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(new CustomResolver2());
        try {
            schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(XmlSchemaFile));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.fail();
        }
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(xmlFile)));
    }
```

it passes without an issue (single xml with single xsd).
However, the following test (a nested file, employee->person)

```java
    @Test
    public void TestStreamingFromFileComposite2() throws SAXException, IOException {
        String employeeXmlSchemaFile = "../mocks/xsd/Employee.xsd";
        String employeeXmlFile = "../mocks/employee.xml";
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = null;
        schemaFactory.setResourceResolver(new CustomResolver2());
        try {
            schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(employeeXmlSchemaFile));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(employeeXmlFile)));
    }
```

fails with `A schema cannot contain two global components with the same name; this schema contains two occurrences of 'http://www.w3.org/2002/ws/databinding/examples/6/09/,Employee'.`.

However, when I run this test (same 4 files, mind you) with no custom resolver, it passes:

```java
 @Test
    public void TestWithNoCustomResolver() throws IOException, SAXException {
        String employeeXmlSchemaFile = "../mocks/xsd/Employee.xsd";
        String employeeXmlFile = "../mocks/employee.xml";
        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = null;
        try {
            schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(employeeXmlSchemaFile));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.validate(new StreamSource(new File(employeeXmlFile)));
    }
```

I looked everywhere for sample code, didn't find anything that works.
anyone can shed some light here?
Thanks!

Comment: Once that pastebin link expires, your question will be useless to future readers.  For that reason, please include your entire LSResourceResolver implementation code directly in your question.  Also, remove the try/catch from each of your tests.  Letting any exceptions propagate will let your test fail as intended, and has the additional benefit of letting you see the full stack trace and explanation for the failure in the test report.  (You do want to know why something failed, right?)

Comment: there is no expiration date on these pages. you can take a look. massive amounts of code obfuscate the question, this is why I put it in another location.

Comment: That class is not massive.  Stack Overflow questions need to be self-contained and meaningful regardless of the content of other sites.